# To open a word document from the same folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to open a word document from the same folder using below coding. I got following error. I using Word 2016

[image]

Comment: use different variable name. word is used for the word namespace

Comment: I am new to vba. Can you exactly tell me which variable should be renamed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Word VBA, you don't need to create any of those objects:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Documents.Open ActiveDocument.Path & "\myfile.docx"
End Sub
```

Comment: If I need to open a file with `xxx_myfile.docx`, is there any code for this (note: `xxx` will keep on changing according the project name but there will be a common suffix word **`myfile.docx`**)

Comment: @ARYF you will need separate question for that with more detail on sample input, expected result, and any of your attempts. Maybe `Documents.Open Dir(ActiveDocument.Path & "\???_myfile.docx")`